# open set in subspace

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Could someone check the following?

> Consider $M=\{0\} \cup \{ 2^{-k}: k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. Which of the subsets $\{0\}$ and $\{2^{-k}\} (k\in \mathbb{N})$ are open in $M$?

Am I right to say that $\{0\}$ and $\{2^{-k}\}\; (k\in \mathbb{N})$ are open in $M$?

Since each $\{m\}\subseteq M$ can be written as $\{m\} \cap M$ where $\{m\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

### added a picture to clarify the answer (see comment)

[image: Open subsets]

Comment: I'm afraid not: no singleton $\{x\}$ is open in $\Bbb R$. A non-empty subset of $\Bbb R$ is open if and only if it is a union of open intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to $\{2^{-k}\}(k \in \mathbb{N})$, you are partially correct.

Recall that an open set of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is given by the intersection of that subspace with open sets of $\mathbb{R}$. So if you have an isolated point in $M$, then it will be open in $M$---this is since if $x \in M$ is isolated, there is an open neighbourhood $U$ around it which does not intersect any point of $M$. So $U \cap M = \{x\}$ is open.

Hence, each of the sets $\{2^{-k}\}$ are open.

Now, what can you say about a neighbourhood $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ of 0 and its intersection with $M$? Can you do the same trick?

Comment: The OP's conclusion is partly correct, but this is merely a fortunate accident, since the reasoning is entirely wrong.

Comment: Thank you, that was very clarifying! I've added the 'mental' picture to the question. Around each singleton $\{ 2^{-k}\}$ there is an open ball $U$ in $M$, while that does not exist at $\{0\}$ since it is a limit point.